# How to select rows by year interval with postgres sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datetime

I have a table with some data from patients at health public system. I have two dates at this table, the date of the disease notification and the date of birth of the patient, like that:

```
notification_date | birth_date 
------------------+-----------------
 2013-02-19       | 2013-02-17
 2015-01-28       | 1984-01-22
 2015-02-08       | 1989-10-04
 2015-01-09       | 1984-05-25
 2016-01-28       | 1988-04-26
 2016-01-06       | 1986-05-20
```

As you can see, by getting the year interval from this two columns, I can find out how old were the patient at the time the disease was notified. I need to query how many people had the age like < 4 years when the disease was notified.

Something like that:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) 
FROM notifications 
WHERE age(notification_date, birth_date) < 4 years;
```

Is this query where I need an specific interval even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use direct date comparisons:

```
select count(*)
from notifications n
where notification_date < birthdate  + interval '4 year';
```

The use of a function such as `age()` seems unnecessarily cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

Try `DATE_PART` with `Count(*)`

```
SELECT count(*) FROM notifications WHERE DATE_PART('year',age(notification_date, birth_date)) < 4;
```

This functions will give you **full** years between two dates.

Read more here if You need:
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-date_part/

Answer (score 0):

Postgres understands interval arithemtics, so consider:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM notifications 
WHERE age(notification_date, birth_date) < interval '4 years';
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=6a6050f20b68740f45d483176e70e91a)**

For your sample data, there is only one record that satisfy the condition, so the query yields `1`.